# How to add public url to nginx reverse proxy with a access token

Tags: nginx, web, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using a public URL and adding it to my Nginx reverse proxy. I have come across a bad request error when I run my nginx.conf configurations file. I have an access token that also needs to be added

Below is my nginx.conf file.

Any recommendations ?

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    set  $allowOriginSite *;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    # External settings, do not remove


    #ENV_ACCESS_LOG
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


    location /test/ {
      proxy_pass https://a***.***.com;
    
    }

   }
}
```

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using the Nginx rewrite modules. I have posted a link below.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

```
location /test/ {
rewrite ^/test(.*) https://URL$1 break;
```